# How to dynamically exclude non-copyable fields in trigger tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Background: I am trying to have an `after update` trigger which stores the changed values dynamically into another table. Since this trigger should be generic and easy to transfer to other tables and won't cause problems, if I add additional columns (If my whole code should be required to solve this, I'll update the question)

While trying to do this, I encounter following issue: I want to store the `inserted` table into an temporary table, which I do in this way:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #tempINSERTED 
FROM INSERTED
```

But the original table contains both: `ntext` and `timestamp` columns which aren't allowed in temporary tables.

Another approach I tried, was looping through the system table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and build a SQL statement as a string excluding non-copyable columns, but this way I cannot access the `inserted` table. - I already figured I cannot access `inserted` if I use `sp_executesql`.

So my question: is there a way to access the `inserted` table and exclude non-copyable columns as `ntext`, `text`, `image` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you look at sql server change data capture rather than triggers, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: someone menitoned a similar feature to me, maybe even though exactly this one, im not sure. all i remember is, i wasnt able to get it to work. i'll look into this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want the triggers to run fast. So the better approach would be to generate the `create trigger` code rather than looping through the fields in the trigger itself. Then if the table schema changes you will need to regenerate the trigger.

For your `#TEMPINSERTED` table you can use `nvarchar(max)` in place of `ntext`,
`varchar(max)` for `text` and `varbinary(max)` in place of `image`. You can also use and `binary(8)` or `bigint` in place of timestamp.

I would suggest using a table variable instead of an `#temptable`. I.e.:

```
declare @tempTable table (
   fieldname int, -- and so on
)
```

Comment: i am aware of the alternative datatypes such as binary(8), as well as varchar(max).  i am allowed to apply triggers to the table but not change the datatypes of the columns. - The trigger needs to be generic, because fields of any kind of datatype may be added via the frondend application - therefor i cannot create fixed fields, even in the temp table.

Comment: @knusperpudding, what I mean is the temp table field types need not be the same as the main table field types. E.g. if the main table has `ntext`, leave it, but the temp table should then have `nvarchar(max)` instead.

Comment: i see, i gues i got the idea: so i should 'build' the temp table as String where i can just 'Replace' the `ntext`, etc fields by the alternatives, to get the working datatypes and execute this via `sp_executesql` - afterwards i can do my `INSERT INTO #tempINSERTED Select * from inserted`. - i'll give it a try. - thanks!
 by the way, you mentioned, i could archive this via a table variable, how'd i add columns to it generic via sp_executesql?

Comment: No, as I said, you should generate the whole trigger, table-definitions and everything, once (and then again when the table changes), then nothing dynamic occurs in the trigger itself. What are you actually trying to achieve, by the way?

Comment: i have an extremely flexible table, the users themselves can add their own fields aswell. - but now i need to log any changes happened with user, time, fieldname, fieldvalue (old and new). i need it to keep it that flexible: if users add new fields, it needs to log those ones too, without changing the trigger

Comment: @KnusperPudding, This is something I have implemented myself before. For this you can use a DDL trigger (Database Trigger) to regenerate the table trigger. I.e. so when the table changes, you automatically call a stored proc to regenerate the trigger (and add the column to the audit history table)

Comment: i see! - i've never heared about a DDL trigger so far, i just looked it up quickly, from what i've seen so far, this is amazing. - after some tests my research about the issue adressed in the question failed anyway, since a `Select * From INSERTED ` already leads to the error, if it contains unsupported fields as `text`. i'll try out the idea with the DDL trigger, which sounds pretty awsome. thanks!